# I want to get bright green color

Tags: color, color-theory

I am new to graphic designing and I am told to find out bright green color. I am attaching an image of a bright green I found. I want to know whether I am right or wrong, and if I am wrong, what will then be a bright green?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean? You want the most _visually_ "bright green, or the "technically" bright green? And what is wrong with using what you think best? It boils down to a matter of taste.

Comment: What you perceive as "bright green" many would not. There's no way for anyone to answer this with anything other than what their *opinion* of "bright green" is.

Answer (score 2):

--- GREEN ---

That color if you use the eye dropper in Photoshop is 165 red, 250 green, and 46 blue.

The only colors you can say for sure *aren't* green are the ones where the green value is zero. Everything else is at least a little green.

Technically.

Then anything that doesn't have zero red is at least a little red. And if it doesn't have zero blue, it's at least a little blue.

Technically.

I say technically because that is just how pixels are done, look on Wikipedia:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Pixel_geometry_01_Pengo.jpg

All the color you see on a monitor comes from just those three, because your eye can pick up those three fundamentals of light at different brightnesses. Every other color you see is a mixture of those three colors.

You don't really need to know *why* a color can have some blue and quite a lot of red in it and still seem "green", like this one. But you have to know that it does. One thing all the colors you would feel confident calling green probably have in common is that the brightness of the green part is higher than the other two values.

--- BRIGHT ---

Because the physics way isn't always the easiest to get one color from another, there are other color models. So think of how 0, 0, 0 is black and 255, 255, 255 is white. If you want to get through all the "grays" from black to white each step of brightness is like 1, 1, 1 and then 2, 2, 2 and so on. So one level of brightness meanas you have to change red AND blue AND green.

It would be easier if you could say "no, I've decided I don't want any color, just make this brighter or darker". Then these same steps would just be keeping other values the same, and changing one value meaning the brightness. Maybe 0, 0, 0% and 0, 0, 1% all the way up to 0, 0, 100%.

The word for that percentage is "brightness", the other word you ask about. It's built into the color picker:

[image]

So looking here with your color, at the Hue/Saturation/Brightness (The H/S/B) you are only at 98%. If that is the "bright" you meant, then it's not as bright as it could be as far as Photoshop says...the most would be 100%.

So what happens if you set the red and blue to zero so it is only green, and then the brightness to 100%?

[image]

Then you get the "new color" above (your color is the "current"). That is the brightest green you can send on the Internet. Unless you can tell people to turn off the lights and turn up the brightness on the monitor and then say you got it 110%.